# MySQL TINYINT negative numbers get converted to positive values

Tags: mysql, tinyint

In my setup, I have a tinyint(1) column in mysql database table.
I populated it with -1 but when I fetch the values via C# EF framework, the values were coming out to be +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this a known <s>bug</s> "behaviour" with tinyint if connection string does not explicitly mention not to convert tinyint negative to boolean as per https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33044.

Edit as pointed by @ysth : the link is talking about different toolset but I guess the outcome is same for my toolset

Comment: that bug is about the migration toolkit.  the mention of the connection string is about the jdbc connector, which I'm guessing it uses.  it sounds like the dotnet connector has a similar "feature".

Comment: @ysth yeah I assumed dotnet can also leverage similar parameter in the connection string - but I did not debug by altering my connection string etc. I missed the part (& thanks for digging in) that the bug report is for migration toolkit - I was using EF framework dealing with a simple fetch of the tinyint column

Comment: note that just selecting (0+yourcolumn) likely works around the client "feature"